# readline then move the pointer back?

Tags: c#, file-io, readline

Is there a function in the `streamreader` that allows for peek/read the next line to get more information without actually moving the iterator to the next position?

The action on the current line depends on the next line, but I want to keep the integrity of using this code block

```
while((Line = sr.ReadLine())!=null)
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to read the entire file into memory and work with it there? Is the size prohibitively large?

Comment: @Yuck, right, the file is too large to be loaded into the memory

Comment: How about having code that works by reading two lines at a time? Do you need to know whats only in the next line or further more?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In principle, there is no need to do such a thing. If you want to relate two consecutive lines, just adapt the analysis to this fact (perform the line 1 actions while reading line 2). Sample code:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("path"))
{
    string line = null;
    string prevLine = null;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (prevLine != null)
        {
            //perform all the actions you wish with the previous line now
        }

        prevLine = line;
    }
}
```

This might be adapted to deal with as many lines as required (a collection of previous lines instead of just `prevLine`).

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently using exactly the same way as yours (even the variable name is accidentally the same as well :)), just wondering if there are other better approaches.

Comment: @Yang (I chose a good name then :)) if something works fine, why changing it? I have used this kind of approaches a lot and never had a problem: it is reliable, clear and quick.

Comment: @Yang I second that. I would speculate this is the most common approach. In fact, I spent several minutes searching for some reasonable way of doing it using a `StreamReader` method and couldn't find anything useful.